# What does "El fin de semana XXL" mean in the context of this picture from Clarin.com?

Tags: tiempo, abreviaturas, argentina, jerga-internet

[image: People on the beach in Mar de la Plata, Argentina - Gente en la playa de Mar de la Plata, Argentina]

What does the abbreviation XXL mean in this picture that I have clipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hace referencia a un fin de semana mucho más prolongado de lo habitual, por sumarse al propio fin de semana (sabado + domingo) uno o más festivos.

Véase, por ejemplo https://www.cronista.com/informacion-gral/fin-de-semana-xxl-de-6-dias-cuando-es/:
"El fin de semana XXL comenzará el 28 de marzo (Jueves Santo y día no laborables), y seguirá el 29 de marzo (Viernes Santo y feriado). Y además del sábado 30 y domingo 31, el lunes 1° de abril será feriado puente por motivos turísticos y el martes 2 el feriado inamovible por el "Día del Veterano y de los Caídos en la Guerra de Malvinas".

Comment: [fin de la semana extra large](https://www.cronista.com/tema/fin-de-semana-extra-large/)

Comment: Gracias. This is similar to "long week-end" in English.